# What is # in DataTable select query

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime, datatable

I wanted to compare a DataColumn's date value. The code is as follows:

```
_DataTable1.Select("enddate>'#" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "#'")
```

The intention is to verify if the value in the column 'enddate' is a future date. Is this the correct way or I need to do something better?

I'm also interested in knowing what that hash (#) means in the query.

Comment: It means a date literal

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: if you don't know what it means why you are using it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [date literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711653%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

A date literal represents a particular moment in time expressed as a value of the Date type